# Ember CLI minifyCSS options

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

There's a minifyCSS option in Ember CLI. It takes a property of enabled and options like this:

```
minifyCSS: {
  enabled: true,
  options: {}
}
```

I can't find much documentation on it. I want to know what are the possible properties inside the options key? I was hoping to set it up to not remove dead codes in my CSS when compiled to production environment for my specific use-case. For example:

```
.some-class {
  color: #fff;
  color: --var(--primary-color);
}
```

The problem is, when compiled to production environment, it will remove dead codes on minification thus leaving only this:

```
.some-class {
  color: --var(--primary-color);
}
```

So yeah, what are the possible properties inside the options key. Hopefully there's one option in there that could solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the available options in broccoli-clean-css. I didn't find any option that would solve my problem. Fortunately, I found a better solution that doesn't involve overriding the default minifyCSS options. I just set both overriding CSS to !important so that the previous property won't get removed.

```
background: #e5e5e5 !important;
background: var(--primary-color) !important;
```

In case anyone's wondering why I'm doing this, it's because not all browsers support CSS var as of the moment. So if a browser doesn't support it, it would default to the `background: #e5e5e5 !important;` property.